# How to modify array of object in Gutenberg (block/editor)?

Tags: block-editor

I want to create accordion plugin, my problem is that I do not know how to modify a state in array of object.

my state in block.json

```
"AccordationDate": {
            "type": "array",
            "default": [
                {
                    "title": "Find relevant media contacts - multiline title",
                    "description":
                      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam quidem ipsam ratione dicta quis cupiditate consequuntur laborum ducimus iusto velit.",
                    "imageUrl": "http://ssse.local/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/P1015596-scaled.jpeg",
                    "baseColor": "249,82,120",
                    "secondColor": "221,9,57"
                  },
```

ny function

```
  function updateTitle(event, ind) {
    // var func = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(attributes.AccordationDate));
    // AccordationDate[ind].title = event.target.value;
return (
prev => (
  setAttributes({AccordationDate: [...prev, {
  ...prev,
 AccordationDate[ind].title: event.target.value }] } )))
}
```

Comment: Using arrays of objects like this for content inside a block is an anti-pattern. Instead it's much easier and more reliable to use an accordion container block that is restricted to an accordion slide/panel block, and put the titles/descriptions on those blocks instead. This eliminates a lot of the work while providing lots of free features, e.g. you can now sort the accordion panels using block controls without having to write all the JS from scratch.

Comment: also avoid storing the URLs of images at all costs, if you ever migrate your site, delete the image, or rename it, those URLs break. It also means your block is incompatible with plugins that filter image URLs. This is why the gallery block stores a list of attachment IDs instead.